# How to remove a list of specific libsvm values from a separate list

Tags: python, list-comprehension, sparse-matrix, libsvm

```
def parseline(line):
    line = line.values.flatten().tolist() # flatten labeled point pandas dataframe to python list
    strLine1 = listToString(line) # custom function just converts list to string for regex operations.
    strLine2 = re.sub(r"^1:1 |2:\d+.\d+ ","",strLine1) # filter string to eliminate first two indices; python string
    splitLine = strLine2.replace("0    ", "").split(" ") # eliminate specific val; split on spaces; python list of strings

    positive = 0 # variable for presence/absence of something instantiated

    for feature in splitLine:
        featureIndex = feature.split(":")[0]
        featureValue = feature.split(":")[1]

        if featureIndex in toRemove: # toRemove is a list of vals to eliminate from each line; this works
            positive = 1 

        newLine = ""

        if positive == 1:
            newLine = [i for i in toRemove not in splitLine] # goal here is to remove values found in the toRemove from the newLine 
            newLine = "1" + " " + newLine
            print(newLine)
        else:
            newLine = "0" + " " + strLine2

        return newLine
```

Here is some of the code for a project I am completing. I've successfully produced a list containing values that I don't want to be included on each line. Said list is called "toRemove".

The conditional statement "if featureIndex in toRemove" works, confirmed by a print statement that prints "This index needs removing from final list" next to each "featureIndex" found in "toRemove".

The issue is that the second conditional statement, (if positive == 1, vs, else) returns a list from the "if positive == 1" condition that is just a duplicate of "toRemove". The "else" condition actually returns the right list.

e.g.

```
'if positive == 1:' list output:
['20', '68', '112', '264', '384', '449', '454', '749', '839',...] #this is just a copy of the 'toRemove' list

'else:' list output:
0 3:0.0 4:1 12:1 36710:1 36725:1 36791:1 86715:1 98190:1
```

I initially tried tackling this as a data-type issue, hence the book-keeping comments next to the transformation statements.

Where am I going wrong here?

EDIT:
The input file being sent thru the 'parseline' function has the following format:

```
1:1 2:00 3:00 4:1 9:1 20:1 40:1... # say index 20 is one of the indices in 'toRemove'
1:1 2:10 3:00 45:1 85:1 99:1 100:1... # say none of the index vals in this line are in 'toRemove'
```

'parseline(line)' removes indices 1 and 2, then parses thru the 'toRemove' list to remove the items from that list, to output the 'newLine' string for every row in the original input file.

the 'newLine' output for the same two example inputs should be

```
1 3:00 4:1 9:1 40:1... #notice index 20 is gone, and its presence in the list is accounted for by the 1 

0 3:00 45:1 85:1 99:1 100:1... #notice since none of the indices in the original list were in the 'toRemove' list,
```

Comment: Do you have examples of input with its outputs?

Comment: Hi Dayannex, I've edited the original post to include the original inputs, and the desired outputs for each scenario (presence or absence of the index in the 'toRemove' list). Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Was a question of data-type. Issue has been resolved. Thanks to all.